# How do I clone a repository when I'm behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, mercurial

There's an option `http_proxy` which should allow access through proxy, but it's not clear whether this should be in the command line, `.hgrc` or some global variable.

I tried it in the command line:

```
hg --config=http_proxy.host=_proxy server_
```

but I still get a Connection timed out error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually an environment variable, so try

> ```
> http_proxy=http://proxy_server:4242 hg ...
> ```

You should replace 4242 with whatever port your proxy is running on.

Comment: May also need `export`: `export http_proxy=...`

Comment: http_proxy also works with https URLs. (Some other programs requires a separate https_proxy environment variable; Hg doesn't.)

Answer (score 5):

I can successfully use the following command:

```
hg clone <TheURl> <Optional Folder Name> --config http_proxy.host=<proxy URL>
```

And obviously by replacing any <> instances with the relevant details.

Comment: It says:hg: --config could not be shortened

Comment: @DmitryIlukhin I guess a lot can happen in 3 years, don't use Mercurial anymore so I'm not sure if the command has changed.

Comment: Worked in this format (note there is no "=" after "--config"): `hg pull -u https://hgserver.com/hg/project --config http_proxy.host=192.168.0.249:8080`

Comment: I confirm the `=` is not needed - can someone with higher rep make the single-char edit to fix that please?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Done :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth :)

Answer (score 3):

You can setup proxy authentication in `.hgrc` file.

It store in `~/.hgrc`. Here is an example.

```
[http_proxy]
host=hostname:port
user=username
passwd=password
```

Note: I currently use SourceTree app on Mac OSX.

Comment: In Windows machines, the file is **`~/mercurial.ini`**.